# Image doesn't cover the whole PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, picturebox

I'm creating an image viewer using C# and having a small issue with scaling (zooming) `PictureBox`.

I have a `PictureBox` inside a `Panel`, and I can zoom (scale) an image using the controls at the top left and using mouse wheel  just fine. However, at some specific zoom scales, the image doesn't cover the whole `PictureBox`.

[image]

For example, SO logo (100x116 pixels) at 100% and at 200%:

[image]

Image at the right is 199x131 pixels, while the `PictureBox` is 200x132.

I've set the `BackColor` of the `PictureBox` to `Red` to make the issue noticeable.

This doesn't always happen, just at specific zoom levels. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

I can set the `BackColor` of `PictureBox` to the `BackColor` of the `Panel` to give the illusion that the image covers the whole `PictureBox`, but I rather fix the problem. If I can't, I'll apply the tricky solution.

Relevant code:

```
float zoom = 1;
Image image = null;

public MainForm(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    image = ImageBox.Image;
    this.ImageBox.MouseWheel += ImageBox_MouseWheel;
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        LoadImage(args[0]);
    }
}

private void ImageBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // disable interpolation (sharper pixels)
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142046(v=vs.110).aspx
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,
        new Rectangle(0, 0, ImageBox.Width, ImageBox.Height),
        0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private void LoadImage(string path)
{
    image = Image.FromFile(path);
    ImageBox.Width = (int)(image.Width * zoom);
    ImageBox.Height = (int)(image.Height * zoom);
    ImageBox.Image = image;
    CenterImage();
}

private void ScaleImage()
{
    ImageBox.Image = null;
    ImageBox.Width = (int)(image.Width * zoom);
    ImageBox.Height = (int)(image.Height * zoom);
    ImageBox.Image = image;
    CenterImage();
}
```

I've also created a [repository](https://github.com/akinuri/image-viewer), in case anyone wants to examine the app live.

Comment: It is a basic floating point accuracy issue, caused by truncating the float to int.  That can easily produce off-by-1 errors.  Caused by the zoom variable, it is not *exactly* 2.0 but a wee bit more or less.  In turn caused by multiplying with 1.1f, that is not a value that can be accurately represented in base 2.  Using decimal instead of float avoids that, but PictureBox itself uses float math and you can't change that.  Setting the BackColor is by far the simple solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't there a way to get around this? Can I assume the offset will always be less than 1, so that I can just add 1 to the variable that falls short? I've changed the math, used fixed zoom value `int zoom = 2`, and drew the image. I can still see the missing pixels (red bg)... I've seen several image viewers that don't seem to have this problem. They either use the `backColor` trick or have a real solution. I guess I'll have to examine their source code.

Comment: Nvm. They all seem to have same issue. I wonder how Windows Photo Viewer works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the rectangle in `ImageBox_Paint`.  Try this:

```
private void ImageBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int add = ImageBox.Width / 200; 

    // disable interpolation (sharper pixels)
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142046(v=vs.110).aspx
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,
        new Rectangle(0, 0, ImageBox.Width + add, ImageBox.Height + add),
        0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Comment: Is this a common approach? I tried this right now, and while it seems to work, it also causes some [problems](http://s1115.photobucket.com/user/akinuri/media/PictureBox.jpg.html). First, this would only work with the SO logo, or at least with an image with similar dimensions. How can I change `200` into a dynamic value, so that it'll work with any image? Also, is it wise to add `add` to both width and height? Shouldn't they receive different values? Can you elaborate on your approach?

Comment: Right now, I'm using `int addW = ImageBox.Width / (image.Width * 2); int addH = ImageBox.Height / (image.Height * 2);` and it's producing correct [results](https://github.com/akinuri/image-viewer). I need an update on this :) How does this work?

Comment: Kind of wished I posted this answer in 2009.

Comment: NearestNeighbor should only be used for zooming perfect integer factors though... and for such pixel zoom you should also set Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to PixelOffsetMode.Half. It's incorrectly documented, but if you don't do this the image will be shifted by half a (zoomed) pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `SizeMode` property of the PictureBox to `Zoom`. Then adapting the size of the picturebox will automatically make the image stretch to its full size.

You don't even need that Paint event listener; it's inbuilt functionality. Just change the dimensions of the PictureBox to the calculated zoomed dimensions of the image and you're done.